# How to integrate a login with facebook button in Java EE project?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'd like to integrate a "login with facebook" button in my Java EE web application. What's the best method?

I'm using jsf primefaces 3.5. Thanks.

Comment: You mean user could loging to your web app using their Facebook credentials ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.adfkickstart.com/facebook-user-authentication-in-java-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [AuthenticRoast](https://code.google.com/p/authenticroast/) to do Facebook Login in Java-EE applications (JSF 2.1, depployed on GF 3/4).

From their website:

> AuthenticRoast allows you to build highly flexible authentication
>   mechanisms for the Java Web tier. This can be anything from HTTP Basic
>   authentication to authenticating with openid, facebook, or your
>   company's Kerberos setup. The authentication modules can be combined
>   at will and even changed at runtime.

First of all you should create a class extending ServletContextListener:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.Registry;


public class ARDAppInit implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
  public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent sce )
  {
    ServletContext sc = null;
    sc = sce.getServletContext();
    // register AuthenticRoast authenticator extending CompositeAuthenticator 
    Registry.forContext( sc ).register( new YouCustomAuthenticatorImpl());   
  } 

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {


    }

}
```

And you should create a listener in web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>it.elbuild.package.package.ARDAppInit</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then you should provide an authenticator, defining a class which extends CompositeAuthenticator. Something like the following class YouCustomAuthenticatorImpl.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.CompositeAuthenticator;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.LogoutManager;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.PluggableAuthenticator;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @author ELbuild, web applications and more...
 */

public class YouCustomAuthenticatorImpl extends CompositeAuthenticator {

@Override
protected Collection<PluggableAuthenticator> createAuthenticators() {
    List<PluggableAuthenticator> result = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * Allow form-based logins.
     */
    result.add(new ARDFormAuthenticator());

    /**
     * Allow Facebook-based logins.
     */
    result.add(new FacebookAuthenticator());

    /**
     * Allow a user to "logout".
     */
    result.add(new LogoutManager());

    return result;
}
```

}

I'm pasting here the just the class I use to handle the FB authentication, please have a look to the comments. It is quite self explanatory if you're familiar with Facebook authentication. The key stuff is to implement the PluggableAuthenticator interface.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import it.elbuild.bjj.db.base.DAOFactory;
import it.elbuild.bjj.entities.Profile;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.AuthenticationRequest;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.PluggableAuthenticator;
import name.aikesommer.authenticator.SimplePrincipal;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

/**
 *
 * @author ELbuild, web applications and more...
 */
public class FacebookAuthenticator extends PluggableAuthenticator {

    private static final String PRINCIPAL_NOTE = PluggableAuthenticator.class.getName() + ".PRINCIPAL";
    public static final String LOGIN_ACTION = "/j_facebook_login";
    public static final String REDIRECT_ACTION = "/j_facebook_redirect";
    public static final String CODE = "code";
    OAuthService service = null;

    /**
     * Overwrite this to specify a different login-page.
     */
    protected String getLoginPage() {
        return "/login.jsp";
    }

    /**
     * Overwrite this to specify a different error-page.
     */
    protected String getErrorPage() {
        return "/login-error.jsp";
    }

    protected String getRegisterPage() {
        return "/register.xhtml";
    }

    protected String getRedirectPage(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String encode = "ISO-8859-1";

        String data = URLEncoder.encode(url, encode);


        return "/social-login.xhtml?redirectto=" + data;
    }

    /**
     * Overwrite this to specify a different path to direct to, if there is no
     * original request.
     */
    protected String getNextPath() {
        return "/";
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationRequest.Status tryAuthenticate(PluggableAuthenticator.AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request) {
        if (manager.matchesRequest(request) && request.getSessionMap().containsKey(PRINCIPAL_NOTE)) {
            manager.register(request, (SimplePrincipal) request.getSessionMap().get(PRINCIPAL_NOTE));
            request.getSessionMap().remove(PRINCIPAL_NOTE);
            manager.restoreRequest(request);
            return AuthenticationRequest.Status.Success;
        }

        String requestURI = request.getRequestPath();
        boolean loginAction = requestURI.endsWith(LOGIN_ACTION);

        if (loginAction) {

            String facebookId = checkCredentials(manager, request);

            if (facebookId != null) {
                request.getSessionMap().put(PRINCIPAL_NOTE, loadPrincipal(manager, request, facebookId));
                String queryString = request.getHttpServletRequest().getQueryString();
                if (queryString != null && queryString.length() > 0) {
                    manager.addQueryString(request, queryString);
                }
                if (manager.hasRequest(request)) {
                    manager.redirectToRequest(request);
                } else {
                    manager.saveRequest(request, getNextPath());
                    manager.forward(request, getNextPath());
                }
                return AuthenticationRequest.Status.Continue;
            }



            manager.forward(request, getRegisterPage() + "?facebook=facebook");
            return AuthenticationRequest.Status.Continue;
        } else {
            boolean redirectAction = requestURI.endsWith(REDIRECT_ACTION);
            if (redirectAction) {
                redirect(manager, request);
                return AuthenticationRequest.Status.Continue;
            }
        }

        return AuthenticationRequest.Status.None;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationRequest.Status authenticate(PluggableAuthenticator.AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request) {
        manager.saveRequest(request);
        manager.forward(request, getLoginPage());
        return AuthenticationRequest.Status.Continue;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationRequest.ManageAction manage(PluggableAuthenticator.AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request) {
        return AuthenticationRequest.ManageAction.None;
    }

    public void redirect(PluggableAuthenticator.AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request) {
        try {
            service = new ServiceBuilder()
                    .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                    .apiKey("YOUR API KEY HERE")
                    .apiSecret("YOUR API SECRET HERE")
                    .callback("YOUR CALLBACK HERE")
                    .debug()
                    .build();

            // Obtain the Authorization URL
            String url = service.getAuthorizationUrl(null);


            manager.forward(request, getRedirectPage(url));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FacebookAuthenticator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public String checkCredentials(PluggableAuthenticator.AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request) {
        String code = request.getParameter(CODE);
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);

        // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(null, verifier);
        System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
        System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
        System.out.println();

        // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
        System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
        OAuthRequest orequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://graph.facebook.com/me");
        orequest.addBodyParameter("get", "name");

        service.signRequest(accessToken, orequest);
        Response response = orequest.send();
        System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject authData = parser.parse(response.getBody()).getAsJsonObject();



        String facebookId = authData.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsString();
        Profile p = null;

        if (facebookId != null) {
            p = DAOFactory.getProfileDAO().findByFacebookId(facebookId);
        }
        if (p == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return facebookId;
        }
    }

    protected SimplePrincipal loadPrincipal(AuthenticationManager manager, AuthenticationRequest request, String facebookId) {
        Profile p = DAOFactory.getProfileDAO().findByFacebookId(facebookId);

        return new SimplePrincipal(p.getUserName(), p.getUserRole());
    }
}
```